# Bitbucket server on redhat linux configured behind apache reverse proxy with https showing mixed content

Tags: linux

I have a bitbucket server version 6.5.0  running  on a Redhat Linux instance. I have configured apache reverse proxy for ssl termination. The virtualhost is configured to proxy all the requests to the backend port 7990.

The login page works with https, but after login it starts showing "mixed content" warning. Can anybody help me to resolve it?

Comment: This is likely to be a problem within your bitbucket server; it probably has links to load content without HTTPS.

Comment: but apart from login page everything else has issues

Answer (score 0):

Configure the base URL of your Bitbucket server to use the HTTPS URL.

From [the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/specifying-the-base-url-for-bitbucket-server-776640392.html):

- In the Bitbucket Server administration area, click Server settings (under 'Settings').
- In the Base URL field, type the URL address of your Bitbucket Server instance (for example, "https://bitbucket.example.com").
- Click Save.

Comment: its already done but still showing mixed content when i login  into the server

Comment: Use your browsers debug console to find out which resources are requested over http.

Comment: anyone can help please